# Is my PHP Conditional Logic Incorrect or I am doing some silly mistake

Tags: php, wordpress

This logic is a PHP logic, but one wordpress function for post meta data →

```
 <?php
               // U need to use this to set the checked="checked"
               $checkbox_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-radio", true);
           ?>
                      <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="meta-box-radio" value="sidebar-rhs"<?php if($checkbox_value == 'sidebar-rhs'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?> /><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/admin/img/sidebar-lhs.png" width="10%" height:auto;>
                      </label>

                      <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="meta-box-radio" value="sidebar-lhs" <?php if($checkbox_value == 'sidebar-lhs'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?>/><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/admin/img/sidebar-rhs.png" width="10%" height:auto;>
                      </label>

                      <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="meta-box-radio" value="sidebar-none" <?php if($checkbox_value == 'sidebar-none'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?>/><img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/inc/admin/img/sidebar-none.png" width="10%" height:auto;>
                      </label>
       </div>
```

Now what this logic does is actually it helps in selecting the Post template.

I am using the above logic, which one true should print a extra class. [This Video will show](https://www.screencast.com/t/OxeUYlAqJC) that the class is not echoing.

I am doing this →

```
<aside class="main-sidebar col <?php if($checkbox_value == 'sidebar-lhs') {echo 'main-sidebar-reverse'; } ?> ">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
</aside>
```

But despite the Left hand sidebar is selected and successfully saved in Wordpress this class → `main-sidebar-reverse` is not getting printed in the HTML.

> THIS IS A WORDPRESS QUESTION, BUT BUG IS A PURE PHP RELATED THAT'S WHY I HAVE POSTED THIS HERE.

Comment: Where do you place the second code? Ity may be in a scope where your variable `$checkbox_value` is not defined. Try `<?php echo $checkbox_value; ?>` to see variable contents if any.

Comment: second code is in index.php ad the first one in functions.php (wordpress)
[Link 1](https://www.screencast.com/t/m99JIR7ZPK2n) [Link 2](https://www.screencast.com/t/3h1NzC5j74tO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable in different files. For most cases it will be out of scope and will not be defined in the other file.

You could try calling the function again:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar col <?php if(get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-radio", true) == 'sidebar-lhs') {echo 'main-sidebar-reverse'; } ?> ">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
</aside>
```

or if you plan to use the contents of the variable more than once in this file:

```
<?php
$checkbox_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-radio", true);
?>
<aside class="main-sidebar col <?php if($checkbox_value == 'sidebar-lhs') {echo 'main-sidebar-reverse'; } ?> ">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar1' ); ?>
</aside>
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but looks like that something else is missing. the extra class is not printing. [Video](https://www.screencast.com/t/cnIa07eu)

Comment: @AdiYogi Try replacing `$object-ID` with `$post_id`.